# NullPointerException with Looper

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, handler, looper

please help me with this. I created a progress bar and update its progress programmatically every 100ms as soon as the application starts(Yeah, it sounds odd, but just for messing-around purposes only). But everytime I run it, I keep getting a NullPointerException. Can someone please help me with this? The log indicates the NullPointerException occurred at "custom_handler.sendMessage(message);" down below. Thank you so much.

```
private Handler custom_handler, main_handler;
private int progress = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //TextView to display the
    text_view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view); progress

    progress_bar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

    //Instantiate a new worker thread
    //but somehow its handler is not instantiated
    //by the time the compiler reaches the "custom_handler.sendMessage(message);"
    //at all, keep getting NullPointerException
    //please look at the comment below the next code block.
    new MyThread().start();

    main_handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            progress_bar.setProgress(message.arg1);
            text_view.setText(message.arg1 + "%");
        }
    };



        Message message = Message.obtain();
        message.obj = "Battery fully charged";

        //keep getting the exception here
        custom_handler.sendMessage(message);


}

class MyThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();

        custom_handler = new Handler(Looper.myLooper()) {
            public void handleMessage(Message message) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message.obj.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        while (progress < 100) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("PSSSHH");
            }
            progress++;

            Message message = Message.obtain();
            message.arg1 = progress;

            main_handler.sendMessage(message);
        }
        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

Comment: post the error and tell us where is NPE located

Comment: You need post the log if you want a good help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Yeah, I did indicate where the error occurred, the log said NullPointerException occurred at  custom_handler.sendMessage(message); I put a comment above it, you guys just didn't see it somehow, and I know what a NullPointerException is, but I don't know why it happens in this case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method `Thread#start()` is asynchronous and non-blocking. It means that your `custom_handler` is going to be instantiated (inside your `MyThread`) **but** creating a new Thread is slower than running a couple of straightforward instructions. At the time the runtime is processing

```
custom_handler.sendMessage(message);
```

the `custom_handler` has not instantiated yet.
You can confirm it by setting a breakpoint right before that line, wait a few of seconds and them resume the execution. It won't crash.

To actually fix it you should instantiate the `custom_handler` before calling it, and preferably in the thread that owns it.